# EntityFramework5 code first , How configure the table splitting relation with different column name?

Tags: c#, sql, code-first, entity-framework-5

I have two tables that I want to query with EntityFramework, a main table is used and this is a second table for storing auxiliary datas, I wish I could make a left join but I can not do it, here are the elements:

```
public class TableA
{
    public int Id {get; set;}
    public string Value {get;} set
}

public class OptionalDataTableB
{
    public int OptionalDataTableBId {get; set;}
    public string OtherValue {get; set;}
}
```

Here the mapping classes

```
public class TableAMap: EntityTypeConfiguration<TableA>
{
    public TableAMap ()
    {
        this.HasKey (e => e.Id);
        this.Property (e => e.Id)
                  . IsRequired ()
             .HasDatabaseGeneratedOption(System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema.DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity);

    }
}

public class OptionalDataTableBMap: EntityTypeConfiguration<OptionalDataTableB>
{
    public OptionalDataTableB ()
    {
        this.HasKey (e => e.OptionalDataTableBId);
        this.Property (e => e.OptionalDataTableBId)
           . IsRequired ()
    }
}
```

I would like to set up a relationship with DbContext

```
public class MyDbContext: DbContext
{
    protected override void OnModelCreating (DbModelBuilder ModelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Configurations.Add (new Mapping.TableAMap());
        modelBuilder.Configurations.Add (new Mapping.OptionalDataTableBMap());
    }
}
```

How configure the mapping can generate this kind of request ? :

```
select * 
from TableA 
    left join OptionalDataTableB On TableA.Id = OptionalDataTableB.OptionalDataTableBId
```

Answer (score 0):

The following from MSDN should answer your question: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/hh134698.aspx

Comment: Please don't just drop a link, but briefly summarize why it applies. Links break quickly. But then, this link does not cover the OP's question.

Comment: Thanks for you answer, but not what I want to do is a relation "one to optional one"